# ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am trying to predict using the learned .h5 file.
The learning model is as follows.

```
model =Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

And I wrote the form of the input as follows.

```
x = np.array([[band1_input[input_cols_loop][input_rows_loop]],[band2_input[input_cols_loop][input_rows_loop]],[band3_input[input_cols_loop][input_rows_loop]]])

prediction_prob = model.predict(x)
```

I thought the shape was correct, but the following error occurred.

> ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

The shape of `x` is obviously `(3,1)`, but the above error doesn't disappear (the data is from a csv file in the form of `(value 1, value 2, value 3, class)`).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Should the first layer be `model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(3,1), activation='relu'))`

Comment: But why read the input as (1,)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The shape of x is obviously `(3,1)`, but the above error continues.

You are right, but that's *not* what keras expects. It expects `(1, 3)` shape: by convention, axis 0 denotes the batch size and axis 1 denotes the features. The first `Dense` layer accepts 3 features, that's why it complains when it sees just one.

The solution is simply to transpose `x`.

Comment: eventually i solved this problem with your adivice. Below is a modified array.

Comment: np.array([band1_input[input_cols_loop][input_rows_loop],band2_input[input_cols_loop][input_rows_loop],band3_input[input_cols_loop][input_rows_loop]])