# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_44 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (3,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, linear-regression

I've searched several similar topics covering similar problems. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336110/valueerror-error-when-checking-expected-dense-1-input-to-have-shape-3-but), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842931/valueerror-error-when-checking-target-expected-model-2-to-have-shape-none-25) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513271/valueerror-error-when-checking-target-expected-time-distributed-19-to-have-3-d), among others. Despite this, I still haven't managed to solve it.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is predicting three parameters using CNNs. The inputs are matrices (which can now be plotted as RGB images after pre-processing) with the initial size of (3724, 4073, 3). Due to the size of the data set I'm feeding the CNN in batches of 16 using the following generator:

```
class My_Generator(Sequence):
""" Generates batches of training data and ground truth. Inputs are the image paths and batch size. """

def __init__(self, image_paths, batch_size, normalise=True):
    self.image_paths, self.batch_size = image_paths, batch_size
    self.normalise = normalise

def __len__(self):
    return int(np.ceil(len(self.image_paths) / float(self.batch_size)))

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    batch = self.image_paths[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]        
    matrices, parameters = [], []
    for file_path in batch:
        mat, param, name = get_Matrix_and_Parameters(file_path)
        
        #Transform the matrix from 2D to 3D as a (mat.shape[0], mat.shape[1]) RBG image. Rescale its values to [0,1]
        mat = skimage.transform.resize(mat, (mat.shape[0]//8, mat.shape[1]//8, 3), 
                                       mode='constant', preserve_range=self.normalise) 
        param = MMscale_param(param, name)                                              # Rescale the parameters
        matrices.append(mat)
        parameters.append(param)
        
    MAT, PAM = np.array(matrices), np.array(parameters)
    PAM = np.reshape(PAM, (PAM.shape[0], PAM.shape[1]))
    print("Shape Matrices: {0}, Shape Parameters: {1}".format(MAT.shape, PAM.shape))
    print("Individual PAM shape: {0}".format(PAM[0,:].shape))
    
    return MAT, PAM
```

The generator is also resizing the matrices by 8 times to fit into memory. The function *MMscale_param* is simply rescaling the parameters to [0, 1].

The generated batches now have shape (16, 465, 509, 3). These are now fed into the following CNN architecture:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 463, 507, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 231, 253, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 229, 251, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 114, 125, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 123, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 56, 61, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 54, 59, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 27, 29, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 25, 27, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 13, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 39936)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              39937000  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 100)               100100    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 20)                2020      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 63        
=================================================================
Total params: 40,431,791
Trainable params: 40,431,791
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As displayed above, the last layer in the model expects the input to be (None, 3). If I understand this correct, "any" batch size value could be replaced by "None" here, so my input, (16, 3) or (`batch_size`, `number_of_parameters_to_predict`), should be valid. However, I'm still getting the following error message:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (3,)
```

What I find to be very strange is the claim that Dense layer *dense_4* has shape (1, ). But isn't it displayed in the architecture above that it's a (3, ) shape? This should then fit well with the input array's shape (3, ).

I've tried to reshape and/or transpose the array in several ways but without success. I've even uninstalled and reinstalled TensorFlow and Keras in the belief that something was wrong there, but still nothing.

What seem to work however, is to only predict one of the three parameters, giving us an input shape of (1, 0). (Later yielding other, memory related, errors though.) This actually works independently of how I shape the *dense_4* layer, meaning that both (None, 1) and (None, 3) works, which according to my limited knowledge, doesn't make any sense.

Adding the compilation;

```
batch_size = 16
my_training_batch_generator_NIR = My_Generator(training_paths_NIR, batch_size)
my_validation_batch_generator_NIR = My_Generator(validation_paths_NIR, batch_size)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

and the training code as well:

```
model_path = "/Models/weights.best.hdf5"
num_epochs = 10
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_path, 
                           verbose=1, 
                           save_best_only=True)

model.fit_generator(generator=my_training_batch_generator_NIR,
                steps_per_epoch=(len(validation_paths_NIR) // batch_size),
                epochs=num_epochs,
                verbose=1,
                callbacks=[checkpointer],
                validation_data=my_validation_batch_generator_NIR, 
                validation_steps=(len(validation_paths_NIR) // batch_size), 
                use_multiprocessing=True, 
                max_queue_size=1,
                workers=1)
```

So, to sum up: I'm having problems fitting a (3, ) array into, what I believe is, a (3, ) layer. However, the latter is claimed to be of shape (1, ). I must be missing out on something here.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I'm using Keras version 2.2.2 with TensorFlow 1.9.0 backend on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of loss function you are using. Replace that with

```
    loss='categorical_crossentropy'
```

Code should work then.

Comment: Thank you very much @Upasana Mittal! This seems to have solved it. However,  I was about to ask you why as I didn't understand the reason for this. _categorical_crossentropy_ is used when the targets are one-hot encoded and I haven't done that. Reading about the function _to_categorical()_ I now understand that it one-hot encodes the data you feed it. I would upvote your answer if I had the reputation =). Again, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries. You have used sparse_categorical_crossentropy which expects an integer in turn which is not applicable in your case. That's why categorical_crossentropy worked.