# Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (21,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

How to fix the input array to meet the input shape?

I tried to transpose the input array, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336110/valueerror-error-when-checking-expected-dense-1-input-to-have-shape-3-but), but an error is the same.

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (21,) but got array with shape (1,)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, input_shape=(21,), activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

arrTest1 = np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.0,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0])
scores = model.predict(arrTest1)
print(scores)
```

Comment: Tgsmith61591, thank you very much, it works :), just add extra brackets arrTest1 = np.array([[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.0,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0]])

Comment: Kindly accept the answer then...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your test array, `arrTest1`, is a 1d vector of 21:

```
>>> arrTest1.ndim
1
```

What you are trying to feed your model is a row of 21 features. You simply need one more set of brackets:

```
arrTest1 = np.array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0., 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0., 0., 0., 0.1, 0., 0., 0.1, 0., 0.]])
```

And now you have a row with 21 values:

```
>>> arrTest1.shape
(1, 21)
```