# Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have shape (41,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm coding a Visual question answer neural network.

**Model**:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Embedding, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential

# img shape
img_h = 320
img_w = 480
# ----------------------
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 128

# Define CNN for Image Input
vision_model = Sequential()
vision_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(img_h, img_w, 3))) #Probabile errore di dimensioni qui 
vision_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
vision_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
vision_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
vision_model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
vision_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
vision_model.add(Flatten())



image_input = Input(shape=(img_h, img_w, 3))
encoded_image = vision_model(image_input)

# Define RNN for language input
question_input = Input(shape=[41], dtype='int32')
embedded_question = Embedding(input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index)+1, output_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE, input_length=41)(question_input)
encoded_question = LSTM(128)(embedded_question)

# Combine CNN and RNN to create the final model
merged = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([encoded_question, encoded_image])
output = Dense(13, activation='softmax')(merged)
vqa_model = Model(inputs=[image_input, question_input], outputs=output)
```

**Data generator**:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

img_directory= os.path.join(dataset_dir, "train")
import cv2 

thisdict = {
  '0': 0,
  '1': 1,
 '10': 2,
  '2': 3,
  '3': 4,
  '4': 5,
  '5': 6,
  '6': 7,
  '7': 8,
  '8': 9,
  '9': 10,
 'no': 11,
'yes': 12
}



def get_image(question):
    image_name = question.get("image_filename")
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_directory, image_name))
    return(img)

def get_question(question):
    question_text = question.get("question")
    return(question_text)

def question_to_token(question):
    question_list = list()
    question_list.append(question)
    question_token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(question_list)
    return(question_token_list[0])

def padding(question_token):
    # Pad to max question length
    question_token_list = list()
    question_token_list.append(question_token)
    question_padded_list = pad_sequences(question_token_list, maxlen=max_question_length, padding='post')
    return(question_padded_list[0])

def preprocess_question(question):
    question_tokenized = question_to_token(question)
    question_padded = padding(question_tokenized)
    return(question_padded)


def get_output(question):
    question_answer = question.get("answer")
    x = thisdict[question_answer]
    return(x)

def preprocess_input(image):
    """--- Rescale Image
    --- Rotate Image
    --- Resize Image
    --- Flip Image
    --- PCA etc. """   
    return(image)

def image_generator(batch_size = 64):

    while True:
        # Select files (paths/indices) for the batch
        batch_questions = np.random.choice(a = train_data, 
                                         size = batch_size)
        batch_input = []
        batch_output = [] 
        batch_input_image=[]
        batch_input_question=[]

        # Read in each input, perform preprocessing and get labels
        for input_element in batch_questions:
            input_question = get_question(input_element)
            input_question_preprocessed = preprocess_question(input_question)
            input_image = get_image(input_element)
            output = get_output(input_element) 
            input_question_preprocessed
            batch_input_image += [input_image]
            batch_input_question += [input_question_preprocessed]
            batch_output += [ output ]
          # Return a tuple of (input,output) to feed the network
        batch_x_image = np.array( batch_input_image )
        batch_x_question = np.array( batch_input_question )
        batch_y = np.array( batch_output )
        yield( [batch_x_image,batch_x_question], batch_y )
```

Basically i'm generating "couples" of [image,question] and then i map them into the correct answer.

Questions are tokenized using `Tokenizer` (so i obtain a list of integers each one mapping a word in the question) and i get a fixed input length of 41 **after padding them** (41 is the length of the longest question).

At testing time i'm using:

```
out_softmax = vqa_model.predict(x=(image,question_string))
```

But i keep getting the error mentioned in the question title.
I tested my `question_string` data with `question_string.shape` and i get `(41,)` which seems coherent to what my net expects as input size.

I also printed the content of `question_string` and i got 
`[ 3  4 25 16 39  7 66  2  1  5 47  6  1 17 36 51  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]` which is (again) coherent to what i'm expecting.

I also checked this previous question: [Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (21,) but got array with shape (1,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210472/error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-input-to-have-shape-21-but-got-arra) and more or less i understood what is the problem, but i can't find a solution in my case (adding extra backets didn't work for me).

How can i solve this problem? And why i keep getting it even if (as shown above) my array size is actually `(41,)` as required by the `predict` function?

Comment: It's the `batch_x_question` that is error here. Suppose it's not 41?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that we pad all the input answers to length of 41. We load a question of length n, and then we pad it until the length of 41 (which is the max length of all the possible questions in our dataset, so there aren't any question longer than 41 words)

Comment: The problem ia that the model expect `batch_x_question` to have shape `(41,)` but you feed a `(1,)` there, according to the stacktrace.

Comment: I know that it is the problem, but the content I pass to the predict function has size (41,) (tested with shape function), so I don't understand why I get this error even though my input size is actually correct