# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (29,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, sequential, tf.keras

I am doing a multiclass classification problem NUM_Labels (=29) different target variables on textual data using a Glove word embedding with. To do so, I have constructed the simple model below.

```
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 12  
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100 
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 10
NUM_LABELS = len(set(dataset['Label']))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num_words, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH))
model.add(GRU(units=32))
model.add(Dense(NUM_LABELS, activation = 'softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

r = model.fit(x = sentences,
              y=targets,
              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
              epochs=EPOCHS,
              validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT
        )
```

However, I still get the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_5_input to have shape (12,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I've looked at [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336110/valueerror-error-when-checking-expected-dense-1-input-to-have-shape-3-but) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842931/valueerror-error-when-checking-target-expected-model-2-to-have-shape-none-25) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655941/valueerror-error-when-checking-target-expected-dense-44-to-have-shape-1-but), but these still don't tell me what I am doing wrong. Who could help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How's your target data? If it's looks like `[1, 4, 0]` then convert to `one hot` first.

Comment: `keras.utils.to_categorical(y)`

Comment: Indeed, this solved the problem